# Optional::isPresentOrElse -> List<> analog

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream, option-type

Faced to some interesting issue: for example, I have to choose some solutions, depending on whether my `List<>` is blank or not, but I don't want to use simple `if-statement` for refactoring reasons (for example, there are three ugly inner if-s). If I had a nullable object, I could use the `Optional::ifPresentOrElse` solution, but what if the array is not null but just empty? are there any built-in language solutions? I understand that I could write something like `ListOptional`, create my own `ListOptional::isNotEmptyOrElse` there, but perhaps there is another solution?

Comment: Please show some code and/or examples of input and required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand `Optional` as a wrapper against a possibly `null` **instance** providing chainable null-safe methods. Suggested `ListOptional` doesn't make to me any sense as null and empty lists semantically represent the same - a bunch of nothing.

If you want to use `Optional`, you must filter the single list in it whether is empty or not and provide an alternative:

```
List<String> nonEmpty = Optional.of(list)
    .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())                     // is the list empty?
    .orElseGet(() -> Arrays.asList("Hi", "Bye"));  // if so, yield a default one
```

How is this better than using a ternary operator is questionable. I see no advantage over using this or `if`-`else` construct or a wrapper from a 3rd party library:

```
if (list.isEmpty() {
    list = Arrays.asList("Hi", "Bye");
}
```

---

A built-in language solution for handling potentially empty collections is `Stream` API as declarative calls of chained methods, that are not executed on `Stream` from an empty collection. You can understand `Stream` as a wrapper against a possibly empty collection with the goal of processing each element. The same goes to the `Optional` with a difference a single instance is handled (regardless of whether it is a collection or not).

```
List<String> list = Collections.emptyList(); // empty list
List<String> updated = list.stream()
    .filter(str -> str.startsWith("A")       // won't happen
    .map(String::toLowerCase)                // won't happen
    .collect(Collectors.toList());           // yields empty list
```